# Svelte: Error from Prettier when I try use self-closing tags for Components?

Tags: html, tags, components, svelte, svelte-component

I'm a newbie in coding (I have some experience in MERN stack), but I'm new to Svelte and I'm confused about this error:

```
["ERROR" - 7:52:27 AM] Error formatting document.
["ERROR" - 7:52:27 AM] Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "TopHeadingSection" (11:9)
   9 | <main>
  10 |     <section class="topSection">
> 11 |         <TopHeadingSection />
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  12 |     </section>
  13 |
  14 |
SyntaxError: Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "TopHeadingSection" (11:9)
   9 | <main>
  10 |     <section class="topSection">
> 11 |         <TopHeadingSection />
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  12 |     </section>
  13 |
  14 |
```

So basically I have to now use an opening AND closing tag to get rid of the error. Any thoughts on whether I can just ignore the error or would that be bad?

```
<TopHeadingSection />                        // Error

<TopHeadingSection></TopHeadingSection>      // No Error
```

Comment: Did you install the [`prettier-plugin-svelte`](https://github.com/sveltejs/prettier-plugin-svelte)?

Comment: Yeah, but if I use a self-closing tag eg. <NavBar /> ...then I get an error at the bottom of VSCode by the Prettier section.

Here is a screengrab: 
https://i.imgur.com/8EmzRaJ.png

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the configuration of some extension, rather than a problem with the use of Prettier itself.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I tried following some articles about setting up my coding environment with VS Code, but I struggled a lot. If you know any good links, let me know! :)